# Guidelines for designing ASP .Net MVC controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls

I'm developing a big, ritch (lots of client-side js code) website and I'm thinking about standing out a set of reusable controls. And here comes the question: what is the best way to design these controls in MVC?
Yes, I know - there are partial views. But from my point of view this is not enough. What I want is first-class building blocks that I can reuse in my application.
Say I have a control that consists of customer data:

- name
- surname
- email
- phone

Of course I can develop a partial view and reuse it, but I need also other elements:

1. model
2. validation
3. server side call that retrieves / changes the model (proper WCF calls to some application server)
4. presentation logic (same control should be able to render as static text and also a form that allows data change)
   These elements should be **encaplsulated** in one place (a control - component - assembly).

Is my way of thinking reasonable or there are better design patterns in MVC?

m.

Answer (score 1):

Editor and Display templates is a good practice http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Comment: This is nice, but still not what I want - there is no encapsulation. In this solution all parts of the 'control' are scattered around the application: views, display and editor templates, etc.